# Non-Abelian Higgs mechanism of Schwinger in 'Wikipedia

Tags: higgs

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism#Examples in "Non-Abelian Higgs mechanism" quotes an "early electroweak model due to Julian Schwinger. In this model, the gauge group is SO(3).... and the gauge invariance is broken down to U(1) or SO(2) at long distances".
Unfortunately there is no reference for this - does anyone have one ? Thanks

Comment: ref 15 in that very article. But do not neglect his [1957 paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Theory-of-the-Fundamental-Interactions-Schwinger/d518441dde66e713b277edcf8dbce9af83b41a51) under any circumstances.

Comment: ref 15 is a 1.5 page note only, the 1957 paper might be it - Thanks!

Comment: Well, the short paper speculates on the mechanism, and the 1957 one on the model-building and symmetry breaking, notably following eqn (13) and on p 425. He is already comfortable with sigma model concepts, cf pp 415-416, 424-426. Like Gilbert's pioneering papers, he comes and goes, abstracts and hedges. They all did that. PS. This really should have been asked in HSM, not in this SE.